# Non-convex subdivisions of newton polygon of a tropical plane curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polygons, tropical-geometry

This is probably an elementary question, but how come the Newton polygon of a tropical plane curve can't have non-convex subdivisions? Or can it?